# R: Get index names while looping through df elements

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

Say, I have a data frame and I need to do something with its cells and remember what cells I have changed. One way is to loop through indices with two for-loops. But is there a way to do this with one loop?

Perfectly I need something like this:

```
changes = data.frame(Row = character(), Col = character())
for (cell in df){
    if (!(is.na(df))){
      cell = do.smt(cell)
      temp = list(Row = get.row(cell), Col = get.col(cell))
      changes = rbind(changes,temp)
    }
  }
```

Example of what I need:

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6), C = c(7,8,9))
rownames(df) = c('a','b','c')

changes = data.frame(Row = NA, Col = NA)
for (i in rownames(df)){
  for (j in colnames(df)) {
    if (df[i,j] > 5) {
      df[i,j] = 0
      temp = list(Row = i, Col = j)
      changes = rbind(changes, temp)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps compare the initial df with the final df. If your df is numeric subtract the two and check which entries are not equal to 0. You should give us a sample of your data. And what is smt?

Comment: Please give a meaningful minimal working example and the expected result. I suspect this will be solvable in 1 line of code (using a vectorized approach).

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Example added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets rid of both loops

```
df = data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6), C = c(7,8,9))
rownames(df) = c('a','b','c')
changes <- which(df > 5, arr.ind=TRUE)
df[changes] <- 0
```

If you want the format exactly as specified you can sort that out with

```
changes <- data.frame(changes,row.names=NULL)
changes$row <- rownames(df)[changes$row]
changes$col <- colnames(df)[changes$col]
```

and its a simple matter of sorting if you're concerned that the order of the rows matches your example output

Comment: Thanks a lot.That's exactly what I was looking for